# Latex Tables decimal point alignment for specific rows - dcolumn

Tags: tables, dcolumn

I am trying to put together a table that consists out of both text and numbers. Most of the numbers I want to align with respect to their decimal points. Nevertheless, some of the cells contain text and should therefore simply be centered. I managed to use the \multicolumn command to align specific cells correctly. Now I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to align whole rows (e.g. Row 1) instead of writing a \multicolumn command for every cell in that row. Below you can see how my table looks at the moment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Column alignment
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcc}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
Row 1 & \multicolumn{1}{d{3.2}}{555} & 555\\
Row 2 & \multicolumn{1}{d{3.2}}{7.77} & 7.77 \\
Row 3 & \multicolumn{1}{d{3.2}}{99.9} & 99.9 \\
Row 4 & Text 1 & Text 2
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `d` specifier should be in the argument to `tabular`; use `\multicolumn{1}{c}` for the entries that don't fit.

Comment: That still leaves a lot of \multicolumn commands as I basically have 50% of text in my table. The most efficient way would be to have a command that decides whether to decimal point align a row in my table or not.

Comment: If you use siunitx `S` columntype you can just place inside braces the cell's content you want centered.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `siunitx`, where cells that don't fit the numeric scheme have just to be braced and will be automatically centered.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx} % better

% the following two lines are not necessary for siunitx
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{With \texttt{dcolumn}}

\begin{tabular}{ld{3.2}c}
Column 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2} & Column 3 \\
Row 1 & 555 & 555\\
Row 2 & 7.77 & 7.77 \\
Row 3 & 99.9 & 99.9 \\
Row 4 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text 1} & Text 2
\end{tabular}

\section{With \texttt{siunitx}}

\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.2]c}
Column 1 & {Column 2} & Column 3 \\
Row 1 & 555 & 555\\
Row 2 & 7.77 & 7.77 \\
Row 3 & 99.9 & 99.9 \\
Row 4 & {Text 1} & Text 2
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To cut down on the tedium of having to write `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` several times, simply set up a shortcut macro, say,

```
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
```

That'll speed up table creation a lot.

Here's how your code would look with this idea fully implemented:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ l d{3.2} c }
  Column 1 & \mc{Column 2} & Column 3 \\ % <-- note use of \mc
  Row 1    & 555           & 555    \\
  Row 2    &   7.77        &   7.77 \\
  Row 3    &  99.9         &  99.9  \\
  Row 4    & \mc{Text 1}   & Text 2  % <-- note use of \mc
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Using `\phantom` directly, or
2. Incorporating `\phantom` into active characters `#` for digits and `!` for the decimal point.  Encapsulated in the `ptabular` environment.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\#=\active %
\def#{\phantom{0}}
\catcode`!=\active %
\def!{\phantom{.}}
\catcode`\#=6 %
\catcode`!=12 %
\newenvironment{ptabular}{\catcode`\#=\active \catcode`!=\active \begin{tabular}}{\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lcc}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
Row 1 & 555\phantom{.00} & 555\\
Row 2 & \phantom{00}7.77 & 7.77 \\
Row 3 & \phantom{0}99.9\phantom{0} & 99.9 \\
Row 4 & Text 1 & Text 2
\end{tabular}

\begin{ptabular}{lcc}
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
Row 1 & 555!## & 555\\
Row 2 & ##7.77 & 7.77 \\
Row 3 & #99.9# & 99.9 \\
Row 4 & Text 1 & Text 2
\end{ptabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]